# Seeing weird Varonis Event Handler error SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013

I have been seeing following error in Event Viewer of one of the Web Front End servers. I have no clue to what it is referencing to:

```
Event manager error: Could not load file or assembly '14_0_0_0_Varonis.EventHandlerAuditor-5_9_61_25, Version=5.9.61.25, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b90780cbee1df1b6' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Can you share your experience with such error

Comment: Looks like its related to Sharepoint After All as Varonis Technician has answered below. Also Event Viewer Refers to SharePoint Foundation as Event Type. It doesnt make sense to put this on hold editors?

Comment: The blockers are right, the error, while a generic 'SharePoint' error is caused because of a 3rd Party software that is installed, and other SharePoint managers without this software will not encounter them.

Answer (score 0):

I am a Technical Support manager at [Varonis](http://www.varoins.com).

The Event Handler is part of our [DatAdvantage](http://www.varonis.com/products/datadvantage/) product.

This specific component provide audit information for access to the SharePoint application.

If you are unfamiliar with Varonis, please reach out to your IT administrator.
I suggest you open a technical support case with our team as the error indicates there is an issue, either the component is missing, or maybe it just needs updating.

You (or your admin) can access our community and/or open a support case at http://my.varonis.com.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is this covered in MSFT Support plan we have, or additional charge would be applied to open a service ticket with Varonis?

Comment: We are not affiliated with Microsoft. It's part of your Varonis support plan. When buying Varonis, our customers also buy a support/software subscription.

Comment: We havent explicitely ordered Varonis Product, it came with MSFT. Therefore should i reach out to MSFT first or varonis?

Comment: @allegro octopus, it is impossible for me to identify you and provide further details here. Contact us via https://my.varonis.com or http://www.varonis.com/services/support/. After we engage in direct communication, we can provide with with assistance regarding your installation, or direct you to a contact who can assist.